# Writing to Influx DB results points beyond retention policy dropped=1

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I am trying to test continuous queries as per [influx example](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/continuous_queries/).

I am trying to create the measurement with following data.

```
 insert bus_data,passengers=5  complaints=8  1557187200
 insert bus_data,passengers=8  complaints=8  1557188100
 insert bus_data,passengers=8  complaints=8  1557189000
 insert bus_data,passengers=7  complaints=8  1557189900
 insert bus_data,passengers=8  complaints=8  1557190800
 insert bus_data,passengers=15  complaints=8  1557191700
 insert bus_data,passengers=15  complaints=8  1557192600
 insert bus_data,passengers=17  complaints=8  1557193500
 insert bus_data,passengers=20  complaints=8  155719440
```

But this results in error:

> ERR: {"error":"partial write: points beyond retention policy dropped=1"}

Here are my retention policies and oneday is default:

```
----             --------  ------------------ -------- -------
autogen          0s        168h0m0s           1        false
oneday           24h0m0s   1h0m0s             1        true
onemonth         720h0m0s  24h0m0s            1        false
MONTH            720h0m0s  24h0m0s            1        false
YEARs            8736h0m0s 168h0m0s           1        false
```

Answer (score 0):

your default retention policies is 24 hours, but be the time of your data is before 24 hour, so there is no need to write to db, because data is only be saved for 24 hour